# How to configure and start diameter client and server for diameter credit control application using freediameter

Tags: diameter-protocol, free-diameter

Till now I have installed and run freediameter in linux centOS 5.8. CER and CEA messages are exchanged between client and server successfully.

I am looking to embedded diameter credit control application in freediameter client and server. Client should send CCR and server should respond with CCA.

I have gone through freediameter DCCA extensions, but not able to know how to use this extensions to send and receive CCR and CCA. I googled a lot but doesn't get any help.

So all I want is to configure freediameter client and server with DCCA.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried loading dcca extensions but I didn't help. LoadExtension="extensions/dict_nasreq.fdx";

Answer (score 5):

Freediameter provides test_app extension. we can do CCR and CCA using test_app extension.

compile freediameter and test_app extension.

```
cmake -DFLEX_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/local/bin/flex 
-DGNUTLS_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/lib/libgnutls.so
-DGNUTLS_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/include/
-DDISABLE_SCTP:BOOL=ON
-DBUILD_TEST_APP:BOOL=ON ../

make; make install
```

You can find test_app extension configuration file under ./doc . Change it as per requirement.

Just need to Load the test_app extension with conf file.

start freeDiameter server and client.

Raise signal 10 to client application to send CCR. (kill -s 10 PID)

That's it.